# Is there a way to see the missing elements between different rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python

Is there a way to see the missing elements between different rows in pandas dataframe as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['A', 'B'], "col2":['x,yg,z', 'gf,ui,x']})
```

Expected output

```
present_in_A_and_missing_in_B 
['yg', 'z']

present_in_B_and_missing_in_A 
['gf', 'ui']
```

So there is a need to compare between rows across columns if the strings are present or not.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just grab col2, split the strings by the comma, make them sets and substract one from the other.

Comment: Do you only have 2 items? How should it generalize to N rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have more than 2 rows, you could generalize with [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and a `set` difference:

```
from itertools import permutations

s = df['col2'].str.split(',').apply(set)

idx1, idx2 = map(list, zip(*permutations(df.index, 2)))

out = pd.DataFrame({'ref': df.loc[idx1, 'col1'].values,
                    'other': df.loc[idx2, 'col1'].values,
                    'missing': s.loc[idx1].values-s.loc[idx2].values
                   })
```

Or:

```
lst = [set(x.split(',')) for x in df['col2']]
labels = df['col1'].tolist()

out = pd.DataFrame([(labels[a], labels[b], lst[a]-lst[b])
                    for a,b in permutations(range(len(df)), 2)],
                   columns=['ref', 'other', 'missing']
                  )
```

Output:

```
  ref other   missing
0   A     B   {yg, z}
1   A     C      {yg}
2   B     A  {ui, gf}
3   B     C  {ui, gf}
4   C     A       {y}
5   C     B    {z, y}
```

Used input:

```
  col1     col2
0    A   x,yg,z
1    B  gf,ui,x
2    C    x,y,z
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the relevant cell into a list with `str.split()`, and then use `numpy.setdiff1d` to compare.

```
df = df.set_index('col1', drop = True)

A = df.loc['A', 'col2'].split(',')
B = df.loc['B', 'col2'].split(',')

A_not_B = np.setdiff1d(A, B)
B_not_A = np.setdiff1d(B, A)
```